# Synonym for affordable and premium

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice

I am trying to name a product that is both affordable and premium. I want to use only one word e.g XXXXXX product. I have been looking for an adjective that means both premium and affordable but I have not found one yet. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "premium"?

Comment: How does that work? I think _premium_ means _unnecessarily expensive_!

Comment: That will be hard, considering that *premium* and *affordable* are close to being antonyms.

Comment: @Clare By premium I mean very high quality product.

Comment: It's very rare to find one-word adjectives that encapsulate what are normally antonyms.  You're trying to write "even though this is premium, it's not overpriced" in just one word...

Comment: I doubt there is an adjective that means *both* affordable and premium. I guess what is meant by 'affordable' can be defined by the target audience. Note that a [websearch](https://www.google.com/search?q=premium+and+affordable+-insurance) shows that many products are touted as ***affordable and premium***. [This product](http://nikkisvaporbar.com/the-main-difference-between-cheap-and-affordable/) specifically says "we strive to create that perfect mid way between premium and affordable," which again suggests that the two words cannot be reduced to one.

Comment: I think you're probably going to have to broaden your baseline - perhaps far enough to include a word like _Efficacious_ - something productive or efficient, or something of that nature.  That being said, I think this exercise is the least of your worries - in fact it may BE a problem itself.  By that I mean that when you do finally wrangle up this elusive word, nobody is going to know what it means anyway, so why bother limiting your product name to some obscure word that 90% of people won't get?  Just my thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, this is difficult to answer considering that *affordable* and *premium* are almost opposite to one another. So I thought maybe it could be re-described as a product that's *cheap*, but *effective/high quality*. Words that come to mind include **cost-effective** and **economical**. I chose these words because they epitomize the concept of "getting value for your money."

According to [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/economical), the word "economical" means

> Giving good value or return in relation to the money, time, or effort
>   expended

My only doubt about this word is that synonyms for economical lean more towards the side of cheap, inexpensive, low-budget, etc.. However, the main point is the concept of "getting value for your money". This can be very subjective with regards to what's valuable. For example, there are hotels out there that may not be 5 stars but are still very comfortable and affordable. A hotel is just one of many low-budget and high-quality factors that can make up a cost-effective trip.

Another example of this could be American education. Private colleges and universities today in the US have an average cost of [$32,410](https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/pay-for-college/college-costs/college-costs-faqs). However, there are more economical and practical choices for cheaper schooling such as public schools and community colleges. These cheaper schools can be much better in quality than the more expensive schools, depending on how you measure quality. Hence, it may be more cost-effective to go to a cheaper school because it could have the same caliber as or better than the more expensive school.

Comment: slightly off topic, but public/state schools are unable to give (because of rules, laws, and lack of funding) any kind if substantial grants in aid. So, while I agree completely on the potential for quality education, and understand that your example is for the purpose of the original question, the idea that state  schools are cheaper is not *necessarily* true. I personally had one child go to what is/was in the top 5 most expensive schools in the country, and one go to state school. The cost to our family was the same for each.

Answer (score 1):

Not an adjective, but this may work: ***bargain/steal***

ODO:

> **[bargain](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bargain)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **2** A thing bought or offered for sale much more cheaply than is usual or expected:
>   ‘the table was a real bargain’
>
> **[steal](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/steal)** NOUN
>
> **1** *informal* A bargain:
>   ‘at £59.95 it's an absolute steal’

Comment: *Bargain* and *steal* capture how I think about getting a premium product at a low price, e.g., a $250 pair of shoes for $100 -- 60% off!